# How to re-add the 'Home Folder' launcher item?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

I deleted the *Home Folder* launcher item, but now I wish to get it back. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Home Folder" icon is actually a shortcut to Nautilus. To get it back:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `nautilus`.
2. Right-click on the **Home Folder** icon in the launcher and check **Keep in Launcher**.
3. Drag the icon back up to the top of the launcher. (Hint: Drag it to the right first, otherwise the launcher will just scroll.)